# Получение команды CommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand с условием WHERE только по ID - C#

Tags: c#, ado

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(string.Format("select * from TABLE where ID_PAR = '{0}'", Id), Connection.GetConnection(database));
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
OdbcCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OdbcCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
```

Как сделать так, чтобы commandBuilder возвращал команду с условием WHERE только по ID_PAR

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN_1 = ?, COLUMN_2 = ? WHERE ID_PAR = ?
```

В настоящее время возращает такую команду

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN_1 = ?, COLUMN_2 = ? WHERE ((ID_PAR = ?) AND (COLUMN_1 = ?) AND (COLUMN_2 = ?))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите свойство `ConflictOption` в значение `OverwriteChanges`.

```
commandBuilder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
```